# Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: categoria, categoria_id, detalle_compra,

Tags: django, ajax

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I am trying to do an autocomplete with the data from the Product table, I don't know what the reason is since I mention the name of the product but toa it as "name". I've done it but I keep getting this error:

Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: categoria, categoria_id, detalle_compra, ...

Models

```
class Producto(models.Model):
    id_producto = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    def toJSON(self):
        item = model_to_dict(self)
        return item
        
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Producto'
```

Views

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        try:
            action = request.POST['action']
            if action == 'autocomplete':
                productos = Producto.objects.filter(name__icontains=request.POST['term'])
                for i in productos:
                    data = []
                    item = i.toJSON()
                    item['value'] = i.nombre
                    data.append(item)
            else:
```

JS

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: window.location.pathname,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {
                                'action': 'autocomplete',
                                'term': request.term
                            },
                            dataType: 'json',
                        }).done(function (data) {
                            response(data);
                        }).fail(function (data) {
                            alert("Error"); 
                        }).always(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                           
                        })
                    },
```

I have verified that it is not "name" however in none of the files I have made that equivalent. I hope you can help me

Comment: You're passing `name__icontains` to the `Producto` query filter but there is no name field on the Producto` model? You have to filter on a valid field in the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass name_contains in views.py which is not in model Producto.

Try to use this :-

```
productos = Producto.objects.filter(id_producto__icontains=request.POST['term'])
```